# Magento frontend login problem

Tags: magento-1.7, login, cookie

I’m unable to login in my Magento mobile store. I have multiple website Magento store. My main website URL is abc.com and for mobile it is m.abc.com. Perfectly works.

I am using different theme for mobile website and both website have 3 different languages store view.

My problem is that if I logged in my main store before then I couldn't login in my mobile site. If I delete all the cookies then it works.

How can solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like wrong settings in cookie domain.

In short, the problem are two cookies with the same content, and magento/apache/php doesn't know which one to use.

[image]

[image]

I think it isn't important wether frontend or backend, have a look on this blog entry by philwinkle about the problem:

http://blog.philwinkle.com/i-cant-login-to-magento-admin/

Images stolen from philwinkle' blogpost, if it is not ok, tweet me.